# How can I resolve this without using backtrack=true?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, ll-grammar

I'm trying to make a grammar that doesn't have operator precedence, but requires that either you use one operator or enclose them in parenthesis. (Using `test` instead of `id|int_literal etc` and `+` instead of a list of valid operators here for simplicity). So for example:

```
test + test ///valid!
(test + test) + test ///valid!
(test + test) + (test + test) /// valid!
test + test + test /// invalid!
```

Is there any way to write a grammar for this that doesn't require backtrack=true? I don't think left-factoring really makes sense here and I'm not sure how a syntactic predicate would help.

Here's what I have (requires `backtrack=true`):

```
fragment
bexpr : 'test' | '(' cbebr ')';

fragment
cbexpr : bexpr '+' bexpr;

expr : bexpr | cbexpr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [How to remove global backtracking from your grammar](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar).

The ambiguity lies in the fact that both alternatives of `expr` can start with a `bexpr`. You need to get rid of this ambiguity. The key lies in the observation that a `+` only occurs without parentheses if it is the entire expression. So we end up with:

```
expr : operand ('+' operand)?;
operand : '(' expr ')' | 'test';
```

In other words: if an operator expression occurs as an operand, then it must be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: But is there any way to do this without the duplication of the '+'? When there are more operators, it becomes ugly to have long lists duplicated twice.

Comment: FYI, the grammar you have in the question does not allow `(test)`.

Comment: I know. But that's simple enough to add. But that is actually much nicer. Thank you.